# PHP read string from until in textfile

Tags: php, html

Hi I need to extract some image links from a text file.
It should be stored in some variables, so the links can be reused.
I only need the img files ending with image1.jpg

I used this code

```
<?php
    $myfile = fopen("vwe/autos.inc", "r") or die("Unable to open file!");

    // Output one line until end-of-file
    while(!feof($myfile)) {

        $photo1 = fgets($myfile);
        //echo var_export(substr($photo1, 0, 30))."<br>";

        echo "1)".substr($photo1, 10, 30)."<br>";
        echo "2)".substr($photo1, 40, 80)."<br>";
    }

    close($myfile);
?>
```

**Autos.inc looks like this:**

```
<div class='glidecontent'>
    <div id='positiontest'>
        <a href='occasion.aspx' target='_self'>
            <img src='http://site.nl/643607012/image1.jpghttp://sit.nl/643607013/image2.jpghttp://site.nl/643607014/image3.jpg' width='100%' border='0' height='100%' style='float: top; padding: 0px' />
        </a>
        <div id='textonadd'>
            <b>Citro&#235;n C3</b>&nbsp;1.4i Diff&#233;rence</br>
            Bouwjaar: 2004 | Prijs: 3250 euro
        </div>
    </div>
</div>

<div class='glidecontent'>
    <div id='positiontest'>
        <a href='occasion.aspx' target='_self'>
            <img src='http://site.nl/643587726/image1.jpghttp://site.nl/643587727/image2.jpghttp://site.nl/643587728/image3' width='100%' border='0' height='100%' style='float: top; padding: 0px' />
        </a>
            <div id='textonadd'>
```

Comment: What happens with your current code? Also, last function should be `fclose`, unless you wrote `close` function..

Comment: Hi you're right it's a typo, the current code isn't working because it's not seen as 1 text string and on every row there is missing info, instead of only at the begin op the file.

Answer (score 0):

Do something like this

```
$data = file_get_contents("vwe/autos.inc", "r") or die("Unable to open file!");
$images = array();
preg_match_all('/(img|src)=("|\')[^"\'>]+/i', $data, $media);
unset($data);
$data = preg_replace('/(img|src)("|\'|="|=\')(.*)/i', "$3", $media[0]);

foreach ($data as $url) {
    $info = pathinfo($url);
    if (isset($info['extension'])) {
        if (($info['extension'] == 'jpg') ||
            ($info['extension'] == 'jpeg') ||
            ($info['extension'] == 'gif') ||
            ($info['extension'] == 'png'))
            array_push($images, $url);
    }
}
```

Comment: Thanks I will try this tomorrow, I think I think this is what I need! Many thanks!

Comment: Hi something changed in de file auto.inc. Now I have to skip the first image link and  I  want the second link. Can you please help me again? This is a example of the code I want to extract the second link from. : <img src='http://eigenwebsitevwe.export.doorlinkenvoorraad.nl/643573788/image1.jpghttp://eigenwebsitevwe.export.doorlinkenvoorraad.nl/643573789/image2.jpghttp://eigenwebsitevwe.export.doorlinkenvoorraad.nl/643573790/image3.jpghttp://eigenwebsitevwe.export.doorlinke' width='100%' border='0' height='100%' style='float: top; padding: 0px' />